# How to fetch documents based on the count of the elements from pymongo / mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have 4 conditions which I want to use to fetch my documents:

1. data **MUST** be between `from_date` - `to_date`
2. `imageKey` **MUST** be included in `IDS`
3. **EITHER** (*at least 1* of) `"updatedCoordinates.status"` should be in `["ORIGINALLY_UNDETECTED","CHANGED"]`
4. **OR** the length of `updatedCoordinates` should NOT be equal to `predictedCoordinates`

I have created a query for the given 2. Need to know if my 3rd satisfies the **at least 1** condition and how to correctly implement the 4th?

```
from datetime import datetime

from_date = datetime(2022, 9, 25, 0, 1, 1, 0)
to_date = datetime(2022, 9, 28, 23, 59, 59, 0)

QUERY = {"$and":[
    {'imageKey':{"$in":IDS}},
    {"createdAt": {"$gte": from_date, "$lt": to_date}},
    {
        "$or":[
            {"updatedCoordinates.status": {"$in":["ORIGINALLY_UNDETECTED","CHANGED"]}},
            {"$ne":[{"$size":"updatedCoordinates"},{"$size":"predictedCoordinates"}]}
        ]
    }]}

my_collection.count_documents(QUERY)
```

I can use the `Python` function for 3rd and 4th after fetching all the data like:

```
def is_valid(box):
    if len(box["updatedCoordinates"]) != len(box["predictedCoordinates"]): return True
    
    for up in box["updatedCoordinates"]:
        if up["status"] in ["ORIGINALLY_UNDETECTED","CHANGED"]: return True
    return False
```

But it'll be lots of overhead.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
{
 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 12, 10, 1, 47, 693000),
 'imageKey': '12345678901234567890123456789012',
 'updatedCoordinates': [{
   'xmin': 102.6942138671875,
   'xmax': 1020.8214111328125,
   'ymin': 748.9141235351562,
   'ymax': 962.6471557617188,
   'status': 'ORIGINALLY_UNDETECTED',
   },
  {
   'xmin': 84.90644836425781,
   'xmax': 1061.1834716796875,
   'ymin': 1089.3341064453125,
   'ymax': 1381.4041748046875,
   'status': 'CHANGED',
   },
  {
   'xmin': 108.43966674804688,
   'xmax': 1022.5031127929688,
   'ymin': 307.7042236328125,
   'ymax': 546.1324462890625,
   'status': 'UNCHANGED',
   },
  ],
 'predictedCoordinates': [{
   'xmin': 139.69284057617188,
   'xmax': 1008.458251953125,
   'ymin': 733.7783203125,
   'ymax': 951.54638671875,
   'status': 'UNCHANGED',
   },
  {
   'xmin': 155.5401153564453,
   'xmax': 989.7386474609375,
   'ymin': 1175.1036376953125,
   'ymax': 1389.05322265625,
   'status': 'UNCHANGED',
   },
  ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your 4th condition is matching the document to itself, you need an aggregation pipeline. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {$in: ["$imageKey", IDS]},
          {$gte: ["$createdAt", from_date]},
          {$lt: ["$createdAt", to_date]},
          {$or: [
              {$gt: [
                  { $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                      "$updatedCoordinates.status",
                      ["ORIGINALLY_UNDETECTED", "CHANGED"]
                    ]
                  }},
                  0
                ]
              },
              {$ne: [{$size: "$updatedCoordinates"}, {$size: "$predictedCoordinates"}]}
          ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CG7tVSdaOnK)

Comment: When I fetch all the documents and run the `is_valid()` **Without** the eqial length criteria, I get the count of document as `533` which is exactly same as when I use the first 3 conditions in `mongoDB` query. After including length filtering, I get `687` count fromt the `python` function but but running your code gives me `454`. What might be the difference?

Answer (score 1):

For Query 4, use the [`$expr` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) (**new in MongoDb v5**) to build an aggregation to compare the size of the `updatedCoordinates` and `predictedCoordinates` fields.

```py
QUERY = {"$and":[
    {'imageKey':{"$in":IDS}},
    {"createdAt": {"$gte": from_date, "$lt": to_date}},
    {
        "$or":[
            {"updatedCoordinates.status": {"$in":["ORIGINALLY_UNDETECTED","CHANGED"]}},
            {"$expr": {$ne: [{"$size":"$updatedCoordinates"},{"$size":"$predictedCoordinates"}]}}
        ]
    }]}
```

Comment: Nice one, I was not familiar with this